# How can a Lagrangian containing no potential energy be used to describe motion of a pendulum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, potential-energy

I'm reading Leonard Susskind's Theoretical Minimum and I got confused with the task number 5 in the lecture 6. The task is given after considering a particle with no forces acting on it. Its position was represented using polar coordinates and the Lagrangian included only kinetic energy. It was shown that in this case  angular momentum has to be conserved: *d(mr²θ')/dt = 0* ( *'* means derivative).
The task is: apply this result to predict the motion of a pendulum with length *l*. (I can't make a direct quotation because I have the Russian edition of the book, but I think my translation should be close enough to the original). My question is: how can a pendulum even exist if there is no restoring force? Is an equation written with assumption that no forces are present applicable to a system like pendulum? I think I don't get some important details or even the whole sense of Lagrangians. If you have this book please check the task.

Comment: So you're asking if a pendulum without gravity is still really a pendulum?

Comment: not only without gravity, but without any force. because in the Lagrangian there was only kinetic energy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result "angular momentum is conserved when there is no external force" can be used to state "and then when I add an external force, the torque is xx and thus the rate of change of angular momentum is yy".

You are right - there *are* external forces on a pendulum: gravity, and the suspension point. These two forces will not always point in the same direction or have the same magnitude. But the torque they generate can be easily calculated from the horizontal distance of gravity to the pivot.

Comment: think I understand what you mean, but can we really extract this law (rate of change of angular momentum is equal to the net torque) from this equation alone? I mean, it's obvious that this derivative wouldn't be zero if there was something that depends on angle, but shouldn't we construct the Lagrangian from the beginning putting everything that is needed and get the equation?

Comment: Without seeing the original question (in a language I can understand) I'm afraid I can't be sure what they intend - so it's possible my suggestion is off the mark. I agree with you that it would seem preferable to add the force of gravity into the Lagrangian - but for some reason your interpretation of the question is "don't do that". I can't help you more without a source, sorry.